# Unable to pass Props to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using [Material UI, Table Component](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table).
All that has been imported in the Root component. The problem I'm running into is
passing properties to the child component `<UserList />`. I can pass `users` but that's it.

My error is `props are undefined`, which means I'm not passing anything to the child,
but how can I pass users but not `showCheckboxes`? What am I missing here?

**User container**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { fetchUsers } from '../actions/usersActions';
import UsersList from '../components/users/UsersList';

export default class Users extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.dispatch(fetchUsers(''));
  }
  render(){
    const showCheckboxes = 'false';
    return(
      <div>
        <UsersList users={this.props.users} showCheckboxes={showCheckboxes}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Userslist**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Table, TableBody, TableFooter, TableHeader, TableHeaderColumn, TableRow, TableRowColumn} from 'material-ui/Table';

export default function UsersList({ users }, props) {
  const emptyMessage = (
    <p>There are no users</p>
  );
  const usersList = users.map( user =>
    <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Table>
        <TableHeader displaySelectAll={this.props.showCheckboxes}>
          <TableRow>
            <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHeader>
      </Table>
      {users.length === 0 ? emptyMessage : usersList}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components) say:

> This function is a valid React component because it accepts a **single**
>   **"props" object argument** with data and returns a React element.

So your component should look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Table, TableBody, TableFooter, TableHeader, TableHeaderColumn, TableRow, TableRowColumn} from 'material-ui/Table';

export default function UsersList(props) {
  const emptyMessage = (
    <p>There are no users</p>
  );
  const usersList = props.users.map( user =>
    <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Table>
        <TableHeader showCheckboxes={props.showCheckboxes}>
          <TableRow>
            <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHeader>
      </Table>
      {props.users.length === 0 ? emptyMessage : usersList}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, the snippet I was referring to was passing the deconstruction only. Thank you for clearing that up. Also made a mistake in one of the properties that needs cleaned up.

Comment: Yes if you want to pass deconstructed props, you should still pass one parameter but as an object. e.g: `UsersList({ users, showCheckboxes })`

Comment: Problem is I'm not sure what is going to be necessary for that component so passing in just props allows for better reuseability.